# Can't Add ppa:x2go/stable

Tags: ppa, x2go

I am trying to turn a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 into an X2go server.
I have followed the instructions here:
http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:repositories:ubuntu

I have taken these steps:

1. `su`
2. Add the line below to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

   ```
   deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe
   ```
3. `add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable`

I get this message:

```
cannot add ppa: ppa:x2go/stable
please check that the ppa name or format is correct
```

Comment: Can you do `apt-get update`? Or otherwise get any of the `apt` programs to successfully use the network?

Comment: @Maythux could not add an answer there (at least 10 reputation )  :).

Answer (score 3):

I would say a few things.

First, I need to caution you against using the command `su` -- it is a bad practice that can only cause problems.  When you need administrative privileges, you should prefix your normal commands with `sudo`.  If you really need a root prompt, you can use `sudo -i`.

Now I took a look at the x2go wiki page and they didn't intend for you to blindly add that line to the bottom of /etc/apt/sources.list.  If you're not too familiar with how Ubuntu handles packaging, you should spend some time on it.  Luckily, you don't really need to be doing any of this from the command line because Ubuntu provides a graphical way to ensure that you don't drop syntax errors in your sources.list or elsewhere.

In order to use the built-in tools for enabling or disabling certain repositories, try [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html).  This will save you from syntax errors and from messing with system-critical files inadvertently.

Secondly, as soon as you modify any of your ubuntu repositories, you should run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

As this will refresh your package information.  After you run that, you should run

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get -f install
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
```

This will clean up your repository caches. Now try adding the PPA again, this time using sudo:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
```

If it still doesn't work, you'll need to re-run the command using the -m flag and show us the output:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository -m ppa:x2go/stable
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The issue was `sudo` does not load user environment variables. `http_proxy`  and `ftp_proxy` were missing. Strangely, for me only `https_proxy` was  defined for sudoers.

If you are behind a proxy check these:

```
 $ sudo -i
[sudo] password for user: 
# env | grep proxy
# http_proxy=http://10.3.100.207:8080/
# ftp_proxy=ftp://10.3.100.207:8080/
# https_proxy=https://10.3.100.207:8080/
```

> To add a user variable do --
>
> 1. Run `sudo visudo`
> 2. Add the following to the bottom:
>
>    ```
>    Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy SOMEOTHERVARIABLES ANOTHERVARIABLE ETC"
>    ```

Read this [sudo caveat](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables/) for more details.

Comment: This right here! I had the same problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps taken from http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:repositories:ubuntu :

Open terminal and execute following command :

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add following line to the file

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu <my-ubuntu-version> main universe
```

Then execute following command in terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache search x2go
```

Then you may install x2goserver, x2goclient or pyhoca-gui or any other of the available packages.

Comment: Good day.
After all, the same:
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:x2go/stable'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
What'd I do?

Comment: Have you enabled security updates and software updates from universe. If not, then search software & updates in dash and enable them first

Answer (score 0):

As written at http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/fix-cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that.html, a good idea is to reinstall certificates. 
I use `sudo -E` to preserve proxy environment.